# Solving a system of equations using a list of possible solutions

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, code-request, number-theory, number-representation

Well, I have for example the following input and output of a code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
a = 3;
b = 2;
n = 21609;
Select[PowersRepresentations[n, a, b], 
 DuplicateFreeQ[#] && ! MemberQ[#, 0] &]

Out[1]={{1, 38, 142}, {1, 82, 122}, {2, 17, 146}, {2, 34, 143}, {2, 74, 
  127}, {2, 94, 113}, {10, 22, 145}, {10, 97, 110}, {12, 27, 
  144}, {12, 99, 108}, {17, 34, 142}, {17, 58, 134}, {17, 86, 
  118}, {22, 26, 143}, {22, 31, 142}, {22, 65, 130}, {22, 79, 
  122}, {22, 95, 110}, {27, 96, 108}, {28, 35, 140}, {28, 56, 
  133}, {28, 91, 112}, {31, 82, 118}, {36, 72, 123}, {36, 93, 
  108}, {38, 47, 134}, {38, 79, 118}, {38, 86, 113}, {42, 63, 
  126}, {45, 72, 120}, {46, 58, 127}, {46, 82, 113}, {47, 50, 
  130}, {47, 74, 118}, {50, 65, 122}, {56, 77, 112}, {58, 74, 
  113}, {58, 94, 97}, {69, 72, 108}, {74, 82, 97}}
```

Now, how can I find solutions to the following system of equations:

```
Solve[{a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 == n, a4^2 + a5^2 + a6^2 == n, 
  a7^2 + a8^2 + a9^2 == n, a1^2 + a4^2 + a7^2 == n, 
  a2^2 + a5^2 + a8^2 == n, a3^2 + a6^2 + a9^2 == n}, {a1, a2, a3, a4, 
  a5, a6, a7, a8, a9}]
```

Using the possible solutions given in the output of the code from above? I think that I need to check every set of possible solutions but I do not see how I can code that?

Thanks for any help and advice.

Comment: `n = 21609; Solve[{a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 == n, a4^2 + a5^2 + a6^2 == n, 
    a7^2 + a8^2 + a9^2 == n, a1^2 + a4^2 + a7^2 == n, 
    a2^2 + a5^2 + a8^2 == n, a3^2 + a6^2 + a9^2 == n}, {a1, a2, a3, 
  a4, 
    a5, a6, a7, a8, a9}, PositiveIntegers]` produces 1278 solutions in short time.

Comment: I want to use the possible ones that are produced by the first code.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand you. Could you elaborate your comment?

Comment: @user64494 Sorry, English is not my native language so sorry for the misunderstanding. Maybe you can check out the answer given below and the discussion below the answer. I think that my question becomes clear after reading that. Thanks for the time and effort.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any answer below. I repeat  could you elaborate your comment?

Comment: @user64494 Well I need to find {{a1,a,2,a3},{a4,a5,a6},{a7,a8,a9},{a1,a4,a7},{a2,a5,a8},{a3,a6,a9}} (where the order does not matter) such that the stated equation is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since exploring all the combinations of triples and their inner ordering is very slow, this method uses randomization and `ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"]` instead to come up with solutions from your set, where the inner order of the triples is randomized. Change the `SeedRandom` to get other solutions.

```
Remove["Global`*"];

a = 3;
b = 2;
n = 21609;
triples = 
  Select[PowersRepresentations[n, a, b], 
   DuplicateFreeQ[#] && ! MemberQ[#, 0] &];
system = {a1^2 + a2^2 + a3^2 == n, a4^2 + a5^2 + a6^2 == n, 
   a7^2 + a8^2 + a9^2 == n, a1^2 + a4^2 + a7^2 == n, 
   a2^2 + a5^2 + a8^2 == n, a3^2 + a6^2 + a9^2 == n};

vars = {{a1, a2, a3}, {a4, a5, a6}, {a7, a8, a9}};
(** assigns all the trips encountered so far - 
   this will either reduce to False,
   or an expression with outstanding variables,
   or True if all variables are assigned **)
test[trips_] := With[{expr = And @@ system},
  expr /. 
   Flatten@MapThread[Rule, {vars[[;; Length@trips]], trips}, 2]
  ]

SeedRandom[123];
maxsols = 5;
ResourceFunction["BacktrackSearch"][
 (* randomize the order of all the triples and make three choice sets for each block of assignments *)
 Map[RandomSample, Table[triples, {3}], {2}],
(* backtrack if test is False i.e some assignment definitely doesn't work *)
 test[#] =!= False &,
(* solution is correct if test is exactly True *)
 test[#] === True &, maxsols 
 ]

(** results:
{
 {{127, 74, 2}, {58, 97, 94}, {46, 82, 113}},
 {{2, 113, 94}, {74, 82, 97}, {127, 46, 58}},
 {{12, 99, 108}, {27, 108, 96}, {144, 12, 27}},
 {{22, 95, 110}, {95, 110, 22}, {110, 22, 95}},
 {{118, 82, 31}, {82, 31, 118}, {31, 118, 82}}}
 **)
```

Comment: I verified that results are all in the triples by doing `Map[MemberQ[triples, Sort[#]] &, results, {2}]`